# Loading fragment (with google map) gives exception when return

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, inflate-exception

I'm making an Android application with a Google Map. I've got a problem with showing the fragment that contains the map. The first thime I've no exception but if I return to the map I've got this exception:

> **`android.view.InflateException`:** Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class fragment
>
> **Caused by `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`:** Binary XML file line #28: Duplicate id `0x7f0d0090`, tag null, or parent id `0xffffffff` with another fragment for `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`.

[The stacktrace you can find on Pastebin.](http://pastebin.com/AWE9DPXG)

---

Here is my code on my Fragment

```
public class RoeteFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // exception thrown on line below
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_roete, container, false); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        // not so important code for the question.
    }

    public static Fragment newInstance() {
        return new RoeteFragment();
    }
}
```

---

Here you find the xml file `fragment_roete`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:id="@+id/map"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Here is how I replace the old fragment with `RoeteFragment`:

```
_fragmentReplaceListener.newFragment(RoeteFragment.newInstance(_roete));
```

*Note by code above:* `_fragmentReplaceListener` is a declaration of an interface that is impelemented on `MainActivity` and contains this code:

```
@Override
public void newFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frmlytContentMain, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack("transaction_fromOldFragment_toNewFragment");
    transaction.commit();
}
```

*Note by code above:* `frmlytContentMain` is a `FrameLayout`.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14695397/5828664

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/36357365/1320616

Answer (score 0):

use MapFragment instead of SupportMapFragment

```
<fragment 
android:id="@+id/map"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              />
```

Comment: then use  @Override
public void newFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frmlytContentMain, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack("transaction_fromOldFragment_toNewFragment");
    transaction.commit();
}

Comment: The problem is if I do this I've problems with 3 other fragments that I'll replace with the same code. So I've got [this error](http://i.stack.imgur.com/v4olo.png). Anyway, my problem is now solved by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083950/duplicate-id-tag-null-or-parent-id-with-another-fragment-for-com-google-androi/14695397#14695397). Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: OK man enjoy Keep posting questions i will be there for help :P